# Fedora 20 Anki fails with ImportError

Tags: python, traceback, fedora20, anki

I want to install Anki on my Fedora installation, so I did:

```
sudo yum install anki
```

The installing process went fine, but when I try to run Anki the following exception pops up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/anki", line 5, in <module>
import aqt File "/usr/share/anki/aqt/__init__.py", line 32
except ImportError, e:</module>
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Please post the full error traceback!

Comment: edit: it may have to do with some python libraries like simplejson, beautifulsoup or sqlalchemy. I tried to remove them and reinstall anki, it didnt help. Also this error occurs on any anki version i tried to run. The same thing seems happening on archlinux in a slightly different form; their solution was to remove the python libraries and reinstall it (as i did) and then change the line in /usr/share/anki
>#!/usr/bin/env python to #!/usr/bin/env python2.7
here is the link to the archlinux problem:
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/37449
I did not understand the last step..

Comment: @KlausD. this is all what i get in terminal. If there is a way to see more, please tell me how

Comment: Which version of Python? That error syntax (`except Error, name:
`) is invalid in 3.x (in favour of `except Error as name:`).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Python 3.4.1 :: Anaconda 2.0.1 (64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay folks, I've got it myself. The clue was in the last step of [this bug report](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/37449).

For Fedora you need to go into the folder where Anki is installed, then open the `runanki.txt` file and change the first line:

From:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

To:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7
```

Now it works!

Comment: Comment from @javadr: I had a same problem with fedora 24,I used /usr/bin/anki. (anki version is 2.0.36-1)